# ReactJs Nice Url With { hashHistory }

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes

I am learning **Reactjs and routes.**

So the issue is that routes are working, b**ut they add this to url "/#/AboutUs?_k=gb8gte".**

How can I make it, that the Url would be user friendly? Just something like /AboutUs

```
ReactDOM.render(
<Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Layout}>
        <Route path="Today" component={Today}></Route>
        <Route path="EndingSoon" component={EndingSoon}></Route>
        <Route path="AboutUs" component={About}></Route>
        <Route path="Contact" component={Contact}></Route>
    </Route>
</Router>
, app);
```

And this is nav.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Link } from 'react-router'

export default class Nav extends React.Component {
render() {
    return(
        <nav>
            <Link to="Today">Today</Link>
            <Link to="EndingSoon">Ending Soon</Link>
            <img src="img/logo.png"/>
            <Link to="AboutUs">About Us</Link>
            <Link to="Contact">Contact</Link>
        </nav>
    );
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get clean (user friendly) urls, you will have to configure your server. And use `browserHistory` instead of `hashHistory`.

Have a look on the following tutorial from react-router.

https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/10-clean-urls

Hope it helps!

Comment: When I use { browserHistory } It returns blank screen ( no error in console ).

Comment: Have you configured your server?

Comment: @xoomer [There's reason why `hashHistory` is the default](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/Histories.md#should-i-use-hashhistory)